# how to add and manage a JSON file in android OS that is only available to custom system service?

Tags: android, json, android-source

I am developing a new system service in an android project. Can anyone tell me what is the best way to manage create and manage a JSON file that is only accessible to the operating system and not the apps?

Which folder should the JSON file be placed?

How can I read and write this JSON file in my system service?

Answer (score 1):

You could call `getFilesDir()` from a `Context` to get a `File` instance that points to the private application directory. No application (besides yours) will be able to access this directory (access control is granted by Unix file system permissions). This is not valid for rooted devices, though.

Comment: But I am working on a system service at the android os level. I don't have context, and I need a directory to store the json file that is only available to my system service.